# ImportError: cannot import name 'SelectOptions' from 'discord.ui'

Tags: python, discord.py, importerror

Here's my imports:

```
import discord

from discord import app_commands
from typing import *
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import *
from discord.utils import *
from discord.ui import Select, SelectOptions
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

I'm using discord.py and not pycord

My python version is 3.11.3 and my discord.py version is 2.2.2

Please help me

I tried to upgrade everything, from python to discord.py and even reinstalling everything, it still doesn't work, I even asked ChatGPT x)

Comment: Have you tried `from discord import app_commands, SelectOption` and removing the `SelectOptions` from the `discord.ui` import?

Comment: Why do you think that `from discord.ui import Select, SelectOptions` should be a valid import?  Are you following some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `SelectOptions`, it's `SelectOption` and you import it directly from `discord` rather than from `discord.ui`

```py
from discord import SelectOption
```